# How to generate GUID in karate DSL?

Tags: karate

I'm new to the technology,pardon me for the mistakes. Any help from anyone is appriciated. I need to generate random guid in the format 12345ab6-a1df-4f40-b0fe-26df6908f62c .Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#commonly-needed-utilities

```
* def uuid = function(){ return java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + '' }
* def myId = uuid()
* print 'myId is:', myId
```